# Ссылка в пункте списка select

Tags: html

Правильно ли так писать?

```
<option value="tests" ><a href="questions.php/?id=5">Question</a></option>
```

Comment: хотелось-бы услышать мысль, которая подвигла на подобную конструкцию, для чего это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, работать не будет.

Для вашего случая должно подойти такое:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// задаем массив ссылок
var links = [];
  links['tests'] = 'questions.php/?id=5';
  links['tests2'] = 'questions.php/?id=8';
</script>
<!-- ставим переход на страницу из массива по изменению select'а -->
<select onchange="if (this.value) top.location.href=links[this.value];">
  <option value="0" >Перейти</option>
  <option value="tests" >Question 1</option>
  <option value="tests2" >Question 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Просто надо делать без js, только с php.

Comment: Тогда никак) Или свой select делайте, но там тоже на одном css довольно трудоемко.

Comment: Посвятите пожалуйста а с каких это пор у `select` появилось свойство `value` всю жизнь писал:

    this.options[this.selectedIndex].value

Comment: Есть value, да только оно отражает не `select>option.value`, а `select>option.textContent`

Comment: А зачем усложнять, почему бы не запихнуть в `select>option.value` сразу URL вместо ключа массива, в котором хранится этот URL?

Comment: А как вставить путь на файл php&

Comment: Спасибо огромное за пример! Прекрасно работает!

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы была ссылка в option, надо сделать так. Выбираем элемент из списка и автоматически переходим по заданно ссылке в select:

```html
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №1</option>
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №2</option>
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №3</option>
</select>

<select multiple onchange="window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №1</option>
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №2</option>
    <option VALUE="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">Ссылка №3</option>
</select>
```